# Win7 keyboard acts funny as if windows key is pressed all the time

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Sometimes, but too often, my keyboard acts funny, as if the Windows key is also pressed. For example: when I type e in a text editor, no e appears but instead a new File Explorer window is opened, as if I had typed the Windows-E keyboard shortcut. Similary, typing m shows the desktop after minimizing all windows, like Windows-M. This way, I found out that practically every letter of the alphabet has a Windows shortcut.

My system is Windows 7, with Virtual PC windows XP. I do most work in XP, and the problem only happens in Win7. Then, the only way to google for solutions and to write this question is to use XP.

This also excludes any physical problem with the keyboard. But to be 110 percent sure, I tried adding a brand new Lenovo usb keyboard; result: same problem on both keyboards.

The system manager here has never seen something like this, so I hope that anybody on the Internet might have a clue. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I know someone with a similar problem but pressing the windows key once fixes it. That doesn't work for you?

Comment: @CameronS: Next time this problem happens I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @bastos.sergio: You are right. If CameronS's fix does not work, I will repost in superuser.

Comment: Accidentally tripping a sticky keys function. Disconcerting when it happens, kind of like being used to 10-key on the number pad and accidentally hitting the num-lock key, it often happens when you hold down one of the shift keys for too long.

Comment: Doesn't "Virtual PC" have a "command" key of some sorts to perform stuff like Ctrl+Alt+Del on the virtual machine?  I've seen that command key get stuck and affect my main machine many times using Virtual Box.  I suspect this is something very similar.

Comment: @CameronS Today I had this problem again, and indeed pressing the Windows key fixed it. Thanks! (only troublesome to get back to this question with the keyboard in problem-mode to re-read the suggested solution :-)

Comment: @Roland I rolled back this question to remove your edited-in solution and "Fixed" title.   If you found a solution, please post it as an actual Answer.  You're allowed to answer your own questions -- it's allowed (and encouraged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing the windows key twice helps. The first keypress brings up the windows menu, as it should, and apparently fixes the keyboard setup. The second keypress makes the windows menu disappear so you can continue with your actual work.